# Nested if else statements only works on first statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, nested, boolean

I am having an issue with nested if else statements. In this issue, it only executes the first if statement and skips all of the rest, when I want every statement to be executed. The else if statement works fine when there is nothing nested inside it, but when I nest additional if else statements only the first one seems to work. Here is my javascript code:

```
const apiURL2 = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=5604473&appid=6d1d830097a2c0bac1aba2337d0139e6";

fetch(apiURL2).then((response) => response.json()).then((jsonObject) => {
const list = jsonObject['list'];
console.log(jsonObject);
for ( let i = 0; i < 5; i++){

    let divForecastData = document.querySelector('div.weather-forecast-wrapper');
    let temp1 = document.createElement("div");
    let tempday = document.createElement("p");
    let temperature = document.createElement("p");
    let icon = document.createElement("i");
    
    temperature.className = "temp";
    tempday.className = "weekday";
    temp1.className = "day";

    if (i == 0){
      tempday.textContent = "Sat";
      temperature.textContent = list[i].main.temp;
      if (list[i].weather[i].main = "Clear"){
        icon.className = "worked"
      }
      else {
        icon.className = " still worked"
      }
      
    }
    else if (i == 1){
      tempday.textContent = "Sun";
      var far = list[i].main.temp
      var kel = far * (9/5) - 459.67;
      temperature.textContent = Math.round(kel) + "℉";
      if (list[i].weather[i].main = "Clear"){
        icon.className = "worked"
      }
      else {
        icon.className = " still worked"
      }
      
    }
    else if (i == 2){
      tempday.textContent = "Mon";
      temperature.textContent = list[i].main.temp;
    }
    else if (i == 3){
      tempday.textContent = "Wed";
      temperature.textContent = list[i].main.temp;
    }
    else{
      tempday.textContent = "Thu";
      temperature.textContent = list[i].main.temp;
      
    }


    divForecastData.appendChild(temp1);
    temp1.appendChild(tempday);
    temp1.appendChild(icon);
    temp1.appendChild(temperature);
    

}






  });
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparaison are coded with `==` or `===`...

So this is not good.
`if (list[i].weather[i].main = "Clear")`

But `list[i].weather[i]` something doesn't exists, I know because it's there is a big red message that appears on the console just by running the code. You maybe wanted to use `list[i].weather[0]`.

Here is a corrected code snippet

```js
const apiURL2 = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=5604473&appid=6d1d830097a2c0bac1aba2337d0139e6";

fetch(apiURL2).then((response) => response.json())
.then((jsonObject) => {
    let divForecastData = document.querySelector('div.weather-forecast-wrapper');
    
    console.log(jsonObject);
    
    const list = jsonObject['list'];

    for ( let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        const item = list[i];
        
        let temp1 = document.createElement("div");
        let tempday = document.createElement("p");
        let temperature = document.createElement("p");
        let icon = document.createElement("i");

        temperature.className = "temp";
        tempday.className = "weekday";
        temp1.className = "day";

        if (i == 0){
            tempday.textContent = "Sat";
            temperature.textContent = item.main.temp;
            if (item.weather[i].main = "Clear"){
                icon.className = "worked"
            } else {
                icon.className = " still worked"
            }
        } else if (i == 1){
            tempday.textContent = "Sun";
            var far = item.main.temp
            var kel = far * (9/5) - 459.67;
            temperature.textContent = Math.round(kel) + "℉";
            if (item.weather[0].main === "Clear"){
                icon.className = "worked"
            } else {
                icon.className = " still worked"
            }
        } else if (i == 2){
            tempday.textContent = "Mon";
            temperature.textContent = item.main.temp;
        } else if (i == 3){
            tempday.textContent = "Wed";
            temperature.textContent = item.main.temp;
        } else{
            tempday.textContent = "Thu";
            temperature.textContent = item.main.temp;
        }

        divForecastData.appendChild(temp1);
        temp1.appendChild(tempday);
        temp1.appendChild(icon);
        temp1.appendChild(temperature);
    }
});
```

```html
<div class='weather-forecast-wrapper'></div>
```

Comment: Beautiful. Worked nicely and you pointed out what I did wrong, I actually didn't notice I had used assignment instead of comparison. Thank you so much.

Comment: You also made a mistake with days order and looking at the API result, the days you used are not correct, you should get the date with `new Date(entry.dt*1000)` in the loop